# Python function not returning anything - Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, function, while-loop, boolean

The problem with this code below is that apart from the print statement the `check_win()` function is not returning anything I could fix this by ditching all the logic in the while loop and not using functions but I want this code to be crystal clear, any suggestions?

```
board = {
    'a1': '', 'a2': '', 'a3': '',
    'b1': '', 'b2': '', 'b3': '',
    'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''
}

player_one = True

player_one_choice = input("Play player one: ")
if player_one_choice in board:
    board[player_one_choice] = 'x'
    player_one = False

elif player_one_choice not in board:
    print("Wrong input")
print(board)

checkwin = False


def check_win():
    """
    'x' check win logic
    """
    # Vertical check logic
    if 'x' in board['a1'] and 'x' in board['a2'] and 'x' in board['a3']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'x' in board['b1'] and 'x' in board['b2'] and 'x' in board['b3']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'x' in board['c1'] and 'x' in board['c2'] and 'x' in board['c3']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True

    # Horizontal check logic
    elif 'x' in board['a1'] and 'x' in board['b1'] and 'x' in board['c1']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'x' in board['a2'] and 'x' in board['b2'] and 'x' in board['c2']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'x' in board['a3'] and 'x' in board['b3'] and 'x' in board['c3']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True

    # Diagonal check logic
    elif 'x' in board['a1'] and 'x' in board['b2'] and 'x' in board['c3']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'x' in board['a3'] and 'x' in board['b2'] and 'x' in board['c1']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True

    elif 'o' in board['a1'] and 'o' in board['a2'] and 'o' in board['a3']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'o' in board['b1'] and 'o' in board['b2'] and 'o' in board['b3']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'o' in board['c1'] and 'o' in board['c2'] and 'o' in board['c3']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True

    # Horizontal check logic
    elif 'o' in board['a1'] and 'o' in board['b1'] and 'o' in board['c1']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'o' in board['a2'] and 'o' in board['b2'] and 'o' in board['c2']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'o' in board['a3'] and 'o' in board['b3'] and 'o' in board['c3']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True

    # Diagonal check logic
    elif 'o' in board['a1'] and 'o' in board['b2'] and 'o' in board['c3']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'o' in board['a3'] and 'o' in board['b2'] and 'o' in board['c1']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True

    return check_win


while True:
    check_win()

    player_two_choice = input("PLay player two: ")

    if player_two_choice != 'x' and player_one_choice in board:
        board[player_two_choice] = 'o'
        player_one = True
        print(board)
    if player_two_choice != 'x' and player_one_choice not in board or player_two_choice == 'a' or player_two_choice == 'b' or player_two_choice == 'c':
        print("Wrong input")

    check_win()

    if checkwin:
        break

    player_one_choice = input("Play player one: ")

    if player_one_choice in board:
        board[player_one_choice] = 'x'
        player_one = False

    elif player_one_choice not in board:
        print("Wrong input")
        break

    print(board)
```

This is the "output" I am receiving

```
>>>Play player one: a1
{'a1': 'x', 'a2': '', 'a3': '', 'b1': '', 'b2': '', 'b3': '', 'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''}
>>>PLay player two: b1
{'a1': 'x', 'a2': '', 'a3': '', 'b1': 'o', 'b2': '', 'b3': '', 'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''}
>>>Play player one: a2
{'a1': 'x', 'a2': 'x', 'a3': '', 'b1': 'o', 'b2': '', 'b3': '', 'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''}
>>>PLay player two: b2
{'a1': 'x', 'a2': 'x', 'a3': '', 'b1': 'o', 'b2': 'o', 'b3': '', 'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''}
>>>Play player one: a3
{'a1': 'x', 'a2': 'x', 'a3': 'x', 'b1': 'o', 'b2': 'o', 'b3': '', 'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''}
congrats x won
>>>PLay player two: b3
{'a1': 'x', 'a2': 'x', 'a3': 'x', 'b1': 'o', 'b2': 'o', 'b3': 'o', 'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''}
congrats x won
>>>Play player one: 
Wrong input
    
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: The variable `checkwin` in your `check_win()` function is a local variable.  Changing it has no affect whatsoever on your global variable `check_win`.  You need to add a `global check_win` to your program (and you can get rid of the `return check_win` at the bottom if your only intent is to change the value of the global variable

Comment: How can you say `check_win()` doesn't return anything?  You never store or look at what it returns.  BTW, all those `'x' in board[...]` expressions should be `'x' == board[...]`.

Comment: Explanation of @FrankYellin is correct, but the suggestion to add `global` is not good. Yes, it will work, but better initialize the `check_win` inside the function to `False` and then bind the return value to a name when you call the function `checkwin = check_win()`

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for the advice but in and == do the same thing I don't see a difference and @buran what do you mean by ```checkwin = check_win()```

Comment: what does `checkwin == True` means? `checkwin = True`?

Comment: @buran:  Your answer is clearly the better one.  I was just trying to explain why the code wasn't working.

Comment: `in` and `==` do not do the same thing at all.  `in` does a search. `==` does a simple compare.  You want `==`.

Comment: *what do you mean by `checkwin = check_win()`* -- what he means is what I said.  You call `check_win()`, and `check_win` returns a boolean value, but you don't save that boolean value.  You throw it away, so you have now way to know whether someone won.

Comment: then @TimRoberts how do you sugggest I use it?

Comment: @TimRoberts and everyone else tank you fo your help at last it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misspelled the checkwin variable

Change this:

```py
return check_win
```

to this:

```py
return checkwin
```

on line 84

Comment: That's one of the problems.  Even if he fixes that, it won't work, because he doesn't use what `check_win` returns.

Comment: ```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'checkwin' referenced before assignment```

Comment: that's what the program returns when I change ```return check_win``` to ```return checkwin```

Comment: so should I make ```checkwin``` global?